# Installing locust.io error (failed with exit status 2)

Tags: python, locust

I tried both commands:

```
1- pip install locustio
2- easy_install locustio
```

Both gave the same result as shown bellow:

---

```
Searching for locustio Best match: locustio 0.8.1 Processing locustio-0.8.1-
py3.7.egg locustio 0.8.1 is already the active version in easy-install.pth 
Installing locust-script.py script to c:\python37\Scripts Installing 
locust.exe script to c:\python37\Scripts Installing locust.exe.manifest script 
to c:\python37\Scripts Using c:\python37\lib\site-packages\locustio-0.8.1-
py3.7.egg Processing dependencies for locustio Searching for gevent>=1.2.2 
Reading https://pypi.python.org/simple/gevent/ c:\python37\lib\site-packages
\setuptools\pep425tags.py:89: RuntimeWarning: Config variable 'Py_DEBUG ' is 
unset, Python ABI tag may be incorrect warn=(impl == 'cp')): c:\python37
\lib\site-packages\setuptools\pep425tags.py:93: RuntimeWarning: Config 
variable 'WITH_PYM ALLOC' is unset, Python ABI tag may be incorrect warn=(impl
 == 'cp')): Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/e6/0a
/fc345c6e6161f84484870dbcaa58e427c10bd9bdcd 08a69bed3d6b398bf1/gevent-
1.3.5.tar.gz#sha256=7f15861f3cc92f49663ca88c4774d26d8044783a65fbc28071a2bd 
1c7bf36ff0 Best match: gevent 1.3.5 Processing gevent-1.3.5.tar.gz Writing 
C:\Users\work\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-rysrp8s8\gevent-1.3.5\setup.cfg 
Running gevent-1.3.5\setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir C:\Users\work\AppData
\Local\Temp\easy_install- rysrp8s8\gevent-1.3.5\egg-dist-tmp-q9s0ninv warning:
 no files found matching 'changelog.rst' warning: no files found matching 
'Makefile.ext' warning: no files found matching 'known_failures.py' warning: 
no files found matching '.pep8' no previously-included directories found 
matching '_pycache_' warning: no previously-included files matching '.so' 
found anywhere in distribution warning: no previously-included files matching 
'.o' found anywhere in distribution warning: no previously-included files
 matching '.lo' found anywhere in distribution warning: no previously-included 
files matching '.la' found anywhere in distribution warning: no previously-
included files matching 'config.log' found anywhere in distribution warning: 
no previously-included files matching 'config.status' found anywhere in 
distribution no previously-included directories found matching 'doc_build' 
warning: no previously-included files matching '.pyc' found anywhere in 
distribution warning: no previously-included files matching '.coverage' found 
under directory 'src\greentest' no previously-included directories found 
matching 'src\greentest\htmlcov' warning: no previously-included files 
matching 'stamp-h?' found under directory 'deps\c-ares' warning: no 
previously-included files matching 'ares_build.h.orig' found under directory 
'deps\c-are s' no previously-included directories found matching 
'deps\libev.deps' no previously-included directories found matching 
'deps\libuv.deps' warning: no previously-included files matching 'Makefile' 
found under directory 'deps\libev' warning: no previously-included files 
matching 'libtool' found under directory 'deps\libev' warning: no previously-
included files matching 'stamp-h?' found under directory 'deps\libev' warning: 
no previously-included files matching 'config.h' found under directory 
'deps\libev' warning: no previously-included files matching '_corecffi.c'
 found under directory 'src\gevent' warning: no previously-included files found matching 'Makefile' warning: no previously-included files found matching
 'configure-output' warning: no files found matching 'Makefile.ext' warning:
 no previously-included files matching '.deps' found under directory 'deps\c-
ares' warning: no previously-included files matching '.libs' found under 
directory 'deps\c-ares' warning: no previously-included files matching '.deps'
 found under directory 'deps\libuv' warning: no previously-included files 
matching '.libs' found under directory 'deps\libuv' warning: no previously-
included files matching '.deps' found under directory 'deps\libev' warning: no 
previously-included files matching '.libs' found under directory 'deps\libev'
 cl : Command line error D8003 : missing source filename error: Setup script 
exited with error: command 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC
 \BIN\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
```

---

Comment: Make sure you're running the command prompt as admin. Also, ensure you have installed C++ build tools from Microsoft. They're available [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6dt9w0ss.aspx). If that does not work, try utilizing one of the tips from [this blog post on compiling Python extensions](https://blog.ionelmc.ro/2014/12/21/compiling-python-extensions-on-windows/).

Comment: https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/installation.html#installing-locust-on-windows

Answer (score 2):

from the Locust docs:

> On Windows, running `pip install locustio` **might fail depedning on if
>   you have a build environment set up correctly. In that case, the
>   easiest way to get Locust running on windows is to first install the
>   pre built binary package for pyzmq (and possibly for gevent and
>   greenlet as well)**.
>
> You can find an unofficial collection of pre built python packages for
>   windows here: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/
>
> When you’ve downloaded a pre-built .whl file, you can install it with:
>
> ```
> pip install pyzmq‑16.0.2‑cp36‑cp36m‑win32.whl
> ```
>
> Once you’ve done that you should be able to just:
>   `pip install locustio`

Answer (score 0):

Its possible that you have a version of python installed that is not supported by locustio. As of now, locustio is supported by Python 2.7, 3.4, 3.5, and 3.6. If you have a newer version of python (for example, python 3.7), the installation will fail.

Answer (score 0):

I got similar problem but with `exit code 1` when running 
`pip install locustio`.

I can confirm that fail on python 3.7.0, but it works ok on python 3.6.7 with no errors, so it's just a version compatibility issue